# Как сделать компаратор, чтобы элементы с null, были первыми?

Tags: java

Есть "компаратор":

```
    Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

            int r;
            Integer n1 = isNumber(o1);
            Integer n2 = isNumber(o2);

            if(n1 != -1 && n2 != -1) r = n1 - n2; // Это два числа!
            else r = o1.compareTo(o2);            // Иначе это либо число и строка, либо строка и строка

            return r;
        }
    });
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы элементы массива с null значениями, после сортировки были первыми?

Comment: В java 8 - `Comparator.nullsFirst( yourComparator )`

Comment: Да, я уже так пробовал, но не всегда есть "yourComparator" (( Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Arrays.asList("2", "3", "1", null, null)
      .stream()
      .sorted((e1, e2) -> e1 == null ? -1 : e1.compareTo(e2))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо Вам Артем!
Я сделал по своему. Получилось конечно по рабоче-крестьянски:

```
    Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

            int r;
            Integer n1 = isNumber(o1);
            Integer n2 = isNumber(o2);

            if(n1 != -1 && n2 != -1) r = n1 - n2; // Это два числа!
            else {
                    if(o1 == null || o2 == null)
                    {
                        if(o1 == null && o2 != null) r = -1;
                        else if(o1 != null && o2 == null) r = 1;
                             else r = 0;
                    }
                    else r = o1.compareTo(o2);            // Иначе это либо число и строка, либо строка и строка
                 }

            return r;
        }
    });
```

Ваш вариант изящнее, но для меня не очень понятный.